# Gnote / Tomboy WebDAV connecting error

Tags: sync, tomboy, fuse, gnote

If I want to sync my notes with WebDAV server, I get the following error messages in Gnote and Tomboy:

> This synchronization addin is not supported on your computer. Please make sure you have FUSE and wdfs correctly installed and configured

How can I set up FUSE and wdfs?

[image: Gnote WebDAV connecting error]
[image: Tomboy WebDAV connecting error]

There is also a reported bug on Launchpad: [Tomboy Notes cant Sync with WebDav](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tomboy/+bug/863347), but I don't know if it is a bug.

Comment: The answer by Khurshid Alam did not work for Ubuntu 14.04. The step, "./configure" fails with error message:
>checking for WDFS... configure: error: Package requirements (fuse >= 2.5.0 neon >= 0.24.7 glib-2.0) were not met:
No package 'glib-2.0' found I was able to get the code to compile by adding the glib-2.0 package. This command should be run before the "./configure" command.
> sudo apt-get install libglib2.0-dev Create a webdav mount point for tomboy data on your local machine.
Enter the following command from the terminal. I am using an owncloud for webdav services, so your directory str

Answer (score 2):

Since fuse is a part of kernel I think its missing wdfs(webdav filesystem) which is `NOT` in the repository.

## Install underlying libraries:

```
sudo apt-get install checkinstall libfuse-dev libneon27 libneon27-dev
sudo apt-get install python-fuse fuse-utils
```

## Get & install wdfs:

```
wget http://noedler.de/projekte/wdfs/wdfs-1.4.2.tar.gz
tar xzvf wdfs-1.4.2.tar.gz
cd wdfs-1.4.2
./configure
sudo checkinstall
sudo dpkg -i wdfs_1.4.2-1_*.deb
```

> If this doesn't work, then its probably this [Bug:575061](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tomboy/+bug/575061)

## Other Workaround:

- Use SSH note sync instead.
- Use wdfs to mount your webdav share somewhere, and use Local
  Directory note sync and have it point at your webdav share. This is
  exactly what the Tomboy add-in does, anyway.

Comment: Please, after synchronize Gnote, what is the result, the files generated has a name and folders name encoded... so is not readable for any software or web page, isn't it?

Comment: If that's the case, then its a Gnote's problem. Sorry I don't use it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I use Ubuntu 14.04 and was able to get Tomboy notes to sync with webdav on an OwnCloud server installation. I was not able get Tomboy to do a direct sync with `webdav` and `wdfs`. My work around was to use `menu:syncronization/service = "Local Folder"`.

1. You need OwnCloud server access.
2. Install OwnCloud client on the computer you want Tomboy access. It is available in Software Center as "ownCloud desktop sync client"
   with version `owncloud-client 1.5.0+dfsg-4ubuntu1`. This will create
   a folder at `/home/user/owncloud`. Everything in the `owncloud` folder
   will be synced with the OwnCloud server.
3. Close Tomboy application.
4. Copy `/home/user/.local/share/tomboy` folder to `/home/user/owncloud`. You can keep the `.local` copy in case you delete
   your owncloud version.
5. Start Tomboy
6. Goto menu:syncronization/
7. choose service = "Local Folder"
8. choose folder path = `/home/user/owncloud/tomboy`
9. choose "save" button to store your settings

This is working for me.

Comment: Hey! Nice answer, but could you fix up the formatting so it follows our [formatting guidelines](http://askubuntu.com/editing-help)? That would be great! Thanks :)